# How to convert a Contact to Partner user through code?

Tags: partner-portal, partner-communities

I have been looking for a code snippet where I can convert a contact to partner user. Is there any inbuilt function for this .

If not , i think , I have to create a user through code and then put the contact ID in it .. which is not the best way to do ..correct ?? Thanks.

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

There's a "quasi-inbuilt" function for this if you use the UI. See my response to  [adding a contact to community user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55562/adding-a-contact-to-community-user/55594?noredirect=1#comment73000_55594). You might say that its more of a process as opposed to a function in that it's a button that takes you from Contact to the Create User Screen and pre-populates some of the values for you.

If you do this via code, in the case of a Partner User, you'll need to have a ContactId to start with before you create the Partner User that's associated with a Partner Account. A Partner User is a User who already will have a Partner Account with you as well as a ContactId. You might describe them as being similar to a special kind of portal user that also has a role; something that other portal users do not have.

All the code I have is for creating standard portal test users, so I'm not certain how valuable it would be to you. The essence of it would be to do the following:

- create account
- create related contact
- convert account to partner account *See Note
- create Partner User, assigning Role and ProfileId

**Note:** Because this a a Partner User you're creating, I'd expect you to need to convert the Account to a Partner Account after creating it and the related Contact.